# ¿Cómo encontrar el valor máximo de una columna de mySQL con C#?

Tags: c#

Mi problema es que quiero generar un código único por unidad introducida a un sistema de control de inventario, hasta ahora todo va bien pero, en la linea que ya comenté en la parte de abajo me devuelve siempre el valor "0", creo que lo solución es encontrar el valor máximo en la columna "id_articulos" en la base de datos "articulo" y aumentarle "1" pero, no tengo idea de como hacerlo. Ya intenté con la propiedad "Max<>" pero, no dio resultado o no supe implementarla bien.
Notas:

- "List_Fam" y "List_Tipo" son ComboBoxes.
- "articulo" el contexto de mi base de datos.
- "id_articulos" una columna de mi base de datos con la propiedad auto
  increment.
- Se porque devuelve "0" pero, no se como hacer que eso cambie.

  ```
  //Creador del código 
  public string CreadorDelCódigo()
  {
      string a = TextBoxCodigo.Text;
      string nombre = TextBoxNombre.Text;
      string color = TextBoxColor.Text;
      string familia = Convert.ToString(List_Fam.SelectedValue);
      string categoria = Convert.ToString(List_Tipo.SelectedValue);
      string id = Convert.ToString(articulo.id_articulos);//Aquí es donde devuelve siempre "0"


      string CódigoTexto = nombre.Substring(nombre.Length - 1, 1);
      string CódigoTexto2 = color.Substring(color.Length - 1, 1);
      string CódigoTexto3 = familia.Substring(familia.Length - 1, 1);
      string CódigoTexto4 = categoria.Substring(categoria.Length - 1, 1);

      a = CódigoTexto + CódigoTexto2 + CódigoTexto3 + CódigoTexto4 + id;
      return a;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESUELTO:

Solo tuve que modificar unos valores.
En la linea 10 estuvo mi solución `db` representa my base de datos, `articulos` es el nombre de mi tabla y el control `.Max()` sirve para eso, encontrar el valor máximo de alguna columna que en este caso fue la columna `id_articulos` y al final se le suma (`+1`) por que como dice la pregunta es para generar el código de un item en la base de datos que aún no existe, es por eso que se le agrega uno de no ser así se repetiría de nuevo el valor máximo de `id_articulos`

```
public string CreadorDelCódigo()
        {
            pvmEntidades db = new pvmEntidades();

            string a = TextBoxCodigo.Text;
            string nombre = TextBoxNombre.Text;
            string color = TextBoxColor.Text;
            string familia = Convert.ToString(List_Fam.SelectedValue);
            string categoria = Convert.ToString(List_Tipo.SelectedValue);
            int maxVal = db.articulos.Max(x => x.id_articulos) +1;//Linea 10 :D


            string CódigoTexto = nombre.Substring(0, 1);
            string CódigoTexto2 = color.Substring(0, 1);
            string CódigoTexto3 = familia.Substring(38, 1);
            string CódigoTexto4 = categoria.Substring(38, 1);

            a = CódigoTexto + CódigoTexto2 + CódigoTexto3 + CódigoTexto4 + maxVal;
            return a;
        }
```

Comment: No se te olvide [aceptar tu propia respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Saludos

Comment: @sstan gracias, ya quedó mejor explicado.